# Can we convert longitude and latitude to cartesian co-ordinates without elevation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

Can I convert from longitude/latitude (x,y) coordinates to cartesian (x,y,z) without having elevation. I have checked some forms discussing converting longitude/latitude into cartesian coordinates, and here's the code in python.

```
    R = numpy.float64(6371000)  # in meters
    longitude = numpy.float64(lon)
    latitude = numpy.float64(lat)
    X = R * math.cos(longitude) * math.sin(latitude)
    Y = R * math.sin(latitude) * math.sin(longitude)
    Z = R * math.cos(latitude)
```

Problem Statement: I have data gathered from different locations. However, these locations are in longitude and latitude format. Are these two attributes are enough to convert the locations into cartesian format ?. Is the code above is correct ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about code problem.  OP is asking a geodetic question.

Comment: You can't convert a 2D point into a 3D point without inventing new data, unless your 3D space is not based on 3 independent coordinates (e.g. a degenerate coordinate system where X = x, Y = y, and Z = (x + y) / 2 or something)...

Comment: Also, I think this does not belong to SO, perhaps to physics.

Answer (score 1):

You need the distance from the center of the Earth to convert latitude+longitude to X,Y,Z (either [Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) or [Earth-Centered Inertial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial)). Earth-Centered Inertial also requires the time to convert from longitude to angle.

The reason for this is simple: you need three independent variables since it's a 3D coordinate system. Latitude and longitude are only two variables, you need the distance from the center (`R` in your equations above) to do that.

If you are looking for ground coordinates, you can use the [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) to get R in your equations above. But either way you need this information for the coordinate transform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess that's python.
You can rotate the resulting world East or West with those equations, but you need to add this equation to the end of it to rotate North or South:
Z = (Y * sin(Rotate)) + (Z * cos(Rotate)).
This is the z line from a multiply vector by matrix.
You can convert it to fit on a 1920 by 1080 screen with this:
`Conversion = 500.0 / 6371000.0;`
`x = (int)(960.0 + (X * Conversion));'` y = (int)(510.0 + (Z * Conversion));'